# For Loops And Arrays

Tags: vb.net

I need a little help. My code is work 99% correctly except for one little thing.

I'm making what's called "Cafeteria Survey" which tallies responses from a ComboBox, which the user inputs them self.

The issue here is that it tallies (places a *) the number 1 less than the number I chose in the ComboBox.

If I add + 1 on the end of `SelectedIndex`  it places the * with the correct number, but it doesn't do it for #10
responses(ratingComboBox.SelectedIndex) += 1

Any help would be fantastic. Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
Public Class CafeteriaSurveyForm

Dim choices As Integer() = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
Dim responses(0 To 11) As Integer
Dim responseCounter As Integer = 0

' displays histogram
Sub DisplayHistogram()

    outputTextBox.Text = ("Rating" & vbTab & "Frequency")

    For i As Integer = 0 To choices.GetUpperBound(0)
        For ii As Integer = 1 To responses(i)
            outputTextBox.Text &= ("*")
        Next
        outputTextBox.Text &= (vbNewLine & choices(i) & vbTab)
    Next


End Sub ' DisplayHistogram

Private Sub CafeteriaSurveyForm_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ratingComboBox.DataSource = choices
End Sub

Private Sub submitButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles submitButton.Click
    responseCounter += 1

    responses(ratingComboBox.SelectedIndex) += 1

    DisplayHistogram()

End Sub

End Class ' CafeteriaSurveyForm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your display function is a little backward.  Here is what you have now:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To choices.GetUpperBound(0)
    For ii As Integer = 1 To responses(i)
        outputTextBox.Text &= ("*")
    Next
    outputTextBox.Text &= (vbNewLine & choices(i) & vbTab)
Next
```

For every loop it is writing the asterisks to the previous line (because the new line is done after).  If you increase the selected index it wrote them in the correct location but never got to write the asterisks for #10 because it exited the for loop before it got a chance.

This is what it should be:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To choices.GetUpperBound(0)
    outputTextBox.Text &= (vbNewLine & choices(i) & vbTab)
    For ii As Integer = 1 To responses(i)
        outputTextBox.Text &= ("*")
    Next
Next
```

Or even

```
For i As Integer = 0 To choices.GetUpperBound(0)
    outputTextBox.Text &= vbNewLine & choices(i) & vbTab & New String("*", responses(i))

Next
```

Now the choices and responses arrays are synced using the same indexes and are accessed during the same loop iteration.

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance! While problem solving yesterday afternoon, I did switch the If statements around but I flip-flopped EVERYTHING rather than just the outputs. Again, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error is that Responses(i) is defined to be integers in the range 1 to 11. If that range isn't inclusive that when you increment Responses(i) by 1 for the response 10 you will fall out of that range.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I change For ii As Integer = 1 To responses(i) to what you said and it gives me an error. And I can't eliminate the += 1 because that's what counts the *

Comment: I put For ii = 0 To responses(i) As Integer and VB tells me it's a syntax error.

Comment: And if I change the 1 to a 0, it initializes all the "buckets" with a * to begin with.

Comment: It initializes all the buckets with a pre-existing * like setting ii = 0 does.

Comment: I understand now. If you can't eliminate the +=1 it's definitely just going to put an extra * there.

Comment: Have to have the += 1. Thanks for all your help. Anything else you could suggest?

Comment: Yeah I have. VB tells me "Array lower bounds can only be 0," since responses is an array.

Comment: Sorry I meant Dim responses(0 to 12) As Integer.

Comment: Yep. Done that. Doesn't change a thing

Answer (score 0):

Try this out to see if it gives you the expected output.

1. Remove the `responseCounter` variable. It doesn't do anything significant (not any I see anyway).
2. Change the `responses` declaration to `Dim responses(9) As Integer`.
   VB.NET uses zero (0) as the lower bound of an array (and almost every other type of collection) so the statement will create an array of integer with ten (10) elements.
3. Change the `For ii As Integer = 1 to responses(i)` loop block to `outputTextBox.Text &= New String('*', responses(i))`

Comment: responseCounter is actually used in my problem. I added the code for it after I posted here. It keeps track of how many responses there are because I have to disable the Submit button after 20 responses.